# Does gcc-via-nvcc vectorize these sum and max reductions?

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, sum, max

I have a CUDA application that currently uses the thrust library to do sum and max reductions of a vector on the GPU.  I'm finding that for certain vector lengths it is much faster if I send the vector back to the host and compute the sum and max reductions in C++.

The sum and max reductions should be vectorizable on the host.  The memory on the host is linear/contiguous and the compiler I'm using (GCC) supports it.  Given the timings I'm seeing, it seems that the compiler is vectorizing the code, but how do I confirm this?  I don't have any experience with forcing compiler optimizations, but I understand there are some pragma statements that could be used.  (You'll find little information by googling it though.)  Also, I would rather not go digging through assembly to confirm, because I won't understand it.  Is there a compiler setting (in GCC or NVCC) that I can use to force vectorization on the host or find confirmation that the code is being vectorized?

The functions I've written for the sum and max reductions are as follows.  The nvcc compiler is ultimately compiling this, as the functions contain CUDA code.

```
void calc_vector_max_host(double& maxval, double *const vec_h, const double *const vec_d, int len)
{
    //copy device vector to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(vec_h, vec_d, len*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    //vectorized? max
    maxval = *vec_h;
    double* temp = vec_h;
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++, temp++)
    {
        if(*temp > maxval)
        {
            maxval = *temp;
        }
    }
}

void calc_vector_sum_host(double& sum, double *const vec_h, const double *const vec_d, int len)
{
    //copy device vector to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(vec_h, vec_d, len*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    //vectorized? sum
    sum = 0.0;
    double* temp = vec_h;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++, temp++)
    {
        sum += *temp;
    }
}
```

EDIT: the following contains the corrections needed for gcc to auto-vectorize.  The compiler options listed in the comments were also needed.

```
void calc_vector_max_host(double& maxval, double *const __restrict__ vec_h, const double *const __restrict__ vec_d, int len)
{
    //copy device vector to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(vec_h, vec_d, len*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    //vectorized? max
    double local_maxval = vec_h[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        double val = vec_h[i];
        if(val > local_maxval)
        {
            local_maxval = val;
        }
    }
    maxval = local_maxval;
}

void calc_vector_sum_host(double& sum, double *const __restrict__ vec_h, const double *const vec_d, int len)
{
    //copy device vector to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(vec_h, vec_d, len*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    //vectorized? sum
    double local_sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        local_sum += vec_h[i];
    }
    sum = local_sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first, and most important point to make is that nvcc isn't a compiler. It is a *compiler driver* -- it just steers compilation using the host compiler in combination with a couple of custom preprocessing tools which break out the actual GPU code and pass it off to the GPU toolchain. Only a small portion of a typical program gets touched by the GPU compiler and assembler. The rest of the build is done directly with the host compiler and linker.

So all of the code you have posted is compiled by gcc (and could be compiled directly without the use of nvcc). nvcc has an option `-Xcompiler` which can be used to pass whatever options you want to the host compilation trajectory. For vectorisation, you can pass any of the options described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) that your version of gcc supports. You could also use SSE style intrinsics directly to make the compiler's job easier, if you are that way inclined

To see whether vectorisation is already happening in your host code, just use something like objdump/otool (depending on whether you are using Linux or OS X, you haven't said). You will be able to look at a disassembly of the code the compiler emitted, and the presence of vectorised instructions will immediately answer your question.

Finally, it is worth nothing that nvcc has pretty good  [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html) these days and you can find the answer to this and probably every other question you have ever had regarding nvcc by familiarising yourself with it.

Comment: A few comments, just for the record.  The link to the gcc options webpage was helpful.  The code originally posted was not auto-vectorizing after all.  This was due to some missing compiler options.  Specifically, I had to pass all of -ftree-vectorize  -msse2 and -ffast-math using the -Xcompiler flag to get the code to vectorize, as well as ftree-vectorize-verbose=6 to get the auto-vectorize compiler output.  I'm using Linux and tried objdump but didn't find the assembly dump very useful for this problem.  There were also a few problems with the functions, which have been edited.